# Has anybody integrated NCover with TFS?

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, nunit, mstest, ncover

Over the past year my group (some 50 engineers) moved onto Team Foundation Server and are now using it for source control, bug tracking and building.

We have tens of thousands of lines of existing NUnit code that we continue to rely on and which we will never convert to MSTest.

We have our builds set up such that NUnit posts results with each build and we get metrics on build quality from the TFS data warehouse including NUnit status.

What I can't seem to figure out is code coverage metrics. TFS will warehouse coverage data from MSTest but I haven't found the API to post that data (from NCover for instance).

Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: TFS isn't really the issue, it's whatever Continuous Integration tool you're using. Are you using Team Build? CC.NET? Something else?

Comment: Using Team Build/MSBuild

Answer (score 1):

NCover does not have an "api" per say to obtain the data.

What version of NCover are you attempting to read the data from? 1.5.8, 2, 3?

Are you attempting to build a data warehouse of coverage data?

How are you collecting you TFS coverage data? Did you write a parser to read the data?

Thank you,

Joe Feser
NCover